# Run two Web APIs on same IIS site with same port

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I currently have two C# Web APIs. (One is an older legacy version of OData, and I'm creating a new one to start using the newest version; but I need to support both for some time.)

When I launch the solution locally, I can access them both:
http://localhost:10013/odata3/Screen
http://localhost:10012/odata4/Screen

I want them to launch on the same port, how would I configure this?

Comment: The API server code would need a command from client to indicate which application to run.  Then the server would execute the appropriate application.  You can't have two IP connections running on the same PC with the same Source IP, Destination IP and Port number.  The server when it starts running is make a virtual connection to an internal socket so you end up with an error when two applications on the same PC attempt to use the same port number.  The two applications end up with the same 3 parameters the same (source, dest, and port).

Comment: If it can be done in iis-express (and I'm not sure) you could manually edit the `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` file to put both applications in the same site.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can manage this with help of virtual directories.
They are configured easily for full IIS.
For IIS Express you will need to dive into ***C:\Users\#username#\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config*** and configure `sites` element there.

Comment: ...unless you are using VS 2015. Then it is in the solution folder.